# MS Project - Span a task over many days AND allow successor to start right after

Tags: ms-project

I am planning my Master thesis through Microsoft Project. Since some tasks can be exhausting (e.g. writing), I would like to distribute some selected tasks over many days. For example, I am estimating that working on a section of the thesis would take 9 hours, but I would like to distribute the 9 hours over 3 days (3 hours/day).

One example of my setup for a given task is the following:

- Unit type: Fixed Duration
- Duration: 3 days
- Hours: 9 hours.

However, my issue is with the following task. Here is a screen capture:

[image: Example of the bug]

As you may see, the task number 6, which has a work duration of 1h, is automatically setup the next working day. However, it is weird since I obviously have the time to do this task right after its predecessors, the same day its finish (my working hours is 9 to 1h30PM, then having 4.5 hours per day available).
[image]

All allocation is done automatically using leveling. I tried to reset the start and finish date (since Project consider task 5 to finish at the "end" of the day), but I still have the issue. Both working time and Option-->Schedule-->Hours per day are set up at 4.5 hours per day.

Any idea why Project refuse to behave nicely!? Is there another way to better set up my task for a better hours distribution over days?

Thank you for your help!

Maxime

Comment: I have reproduced this but cannot find a solution. MS-Project is not good where a resource has fractional availability and fractional max units. I'd be keen to know how to fix this myself...

Comment: Thank you Marv for the feedback. I am still struggling as well. For the moment, I decided to simply go forward with a simple and linear schedule. More simple. I will manage each weeks the more subtle tasks allocation. 

In addition, for the tasks I would like to allocate in "parallel" with others, I will try to "duplicate" myself as a resource, such as Maxime - Reading, Maxime - Stats. This way, Project should allocate a certain number of hours to each cognitive resources.

Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

I think if you add the peak units field to the time scaled portion of the Resource Usage view - you will have your answer.

Maxine is assigned at 67% Assignment Units to task 3  (3 hours of work each day for 3 days)
Maxine is assigned at 33% Assignment Units to task 5 (1.5 hours of work each day for two days)
Maxine is assigned at 100% assignment units to task 6 (1 hour of work in 1 hour duration)

Both tasks 3 and 5 can be schedules at the same time because her max units is 100% and the assignment units add up to 100%.  However, task 5 & 6 add to 167% so she is overallocated on an **hour by hour** basis.  Set your "Look for overallocations on a" to day by day - she is not overallocated and task 6 can happen concurrently with task 3.